# Data-Href update Status Bar

Tags: javascript, href

I'm looking into using https://github.com/nathanford/data-href on a new site and noticed that when you use it and you mouseover the element, the status bar (in Chrome at least) doesn't appear showing you the address that you will be taken too. Makes sense.

But is there a way I can get the status bar to show the upcoming destination?

Comment: Seems like a bad way to fix invalid markup ?

Comment: Yep, I abandoned using this as reading into it further it does seem a strange idea.